# How to filter evil Regex and filter input with regex in python?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

How to filter evil Regex and filter input with regex in python?

1. Is there security regex library or database that can use a list of regex to filter and check vulnerable input in python?
2. Some regex itself are evil too, how to filter evil or vulnerable regex to protect regex match and regex find etc function in python?
   https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Comment: It is partially unclear what you are asking and partly too broad. Your have two independent questions - please restrict yourself to a single one per post.  As for the first: it is unclear what kind of "vulnerable input" you imagine so it is not clear what should be filtered. Also, why do you want specifically regex instead of other methods of input validation?

Comment: Can you write a (partial) Python compiler in regex? if so, you have something that can "understand" what python does. If that's technologically impossible, then regex isn't the tool to analyze code. Related is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4433386), although it only concerns itself with parsing a data representation format, not even a programming language.

Comment: And no, regexp in theory are never evil. If the code that processes the regexps has a bug or conceptual security flaw, then the code is the problem. And instead of trying to recognize when this bug is abused, just fixing it would be better (or both).

Comment: Then focus on question 2, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Comment: @PrinceMartin From your link: "[an] attack, that exploits the fact that most Regular Expression **implementations** ..." . Anyways, regexps from outside of a server are necessary, the magic word is timeout here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent SQL injection you don't need any regex to filter input. In python use prepared statements. No matter what parameter you put to the prepared statement you have a quarantine that there is no SQL injection.